# How to run one command in many threads in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to make a program which can simulate 500 connections (HTTP Request) to a website. So I want to know how to multiple the http request function and run them all together without manually create many thread by many commands.

Comment: Just create 500 `async` requests and don't `await` them. Then use `Task.WhenAll`. You are now abstracted away from threads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Below code, Using TaskFactory.FromAsync from the TPL.

> Creates a Task that represents a pair of begin and end methods that
>   conform to the Asynchronous Programming Model pattern.

If you are running through console application you should wait to complete all parallel tasks using `Task.WaitAll`

```
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com");
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)await Task.Factory
                                    .FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse,
                                    request.EndGetResponse,
                                    null);
                Console.WriteLine($"Request {i} status is {response.StatusCode}");

            }));
       }

       try
       {
            // Wait for all the tasks to finish.
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
       }
       catch (AggregateException e)
       {
            for (int j = 0; j < e.InnerExceptions.Count; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n-------------------------------------------------\n{0}", e.InnerExceptions[j].ToString());
            }
       }
```

You can replace `for` loop with `Parallel.For`, it will execute task in Parallel

```
Parallel.For(1, 500,
                  index => {
                      // web request
                  });
```

Comment: But you never await the tasks that are run.

Comment: @john correct but i dont know OP main thread

Comment: I'd still argue that you should demonstrate awaiting for it in some way. Imagine he's doing this from a console application. It will exit before all of the requests are completed.

Comment: @john sure I will edit it thanks

Answer (score 1):

is it you mean?

```
for(int i=0;i<500;i++)
{
  Task.Run(()=>YourFunc());
}
```